# ZURB Foundation 4.2.3 - Compass - top-bar doesn't work

Tags: zurb-foundation, navbar, compass-sass

The template is here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/marketing.html

I downloaded this template and one by one downloaded foundation.css, normalize.css and the custom.modernizr,js

The top bar seems to work fine.

I ran updates on the zurb-foundation and compass gems and created a new compass project.

Now when I take that working template and move it into the fresh compass project, update all the paths and change the linked stylesheet from foundation.css to app.css, the dropdowns no longer work on the expanded top-bar.

I have made no edits to any scss or css code. The only edit is changing the link from foundation.css to app.css. These should be the same right?

My workaround is to include both foundation.css and app.css, but this seems like a lot of unnecessary duplication - and it's making it very difficult to tweak the styling.

The files can be viewed at:

http://www.t4dev.com.php53-3.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/transparency/

Comment: I also got that problem with 4.2.3. I reverted to 4.1.6 and the dropdowns worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use the right markup or the js won't work.

Look at the docs http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html and use the sample markup to test if it works.

The template you showed uses a valid markup for the top bar.

Hope that helps :)